# how to embed ReactJS components into blade template?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

I'm ReactJS developer (react, flux, react-router, gulp, nodejs etc...).

How do I embed react components into blade template?
Or, at least, where should I start searching for answer?

Please, let me know, if I can provide any more useful information on this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't embed them in your blade template, your template provides a DOM element which the React component can render its output to. For example, in your template you have:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

and in your javascript/jsx:

```js
React.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you Eelke,
I guess it should be like that: 
i will run react webapp on nodejs server, separately from main website (laravel, blade)
Main website will call api nodejs to fetch rendered to string react component. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I guess you're doing server side React rendering? If that's the case, you need two separate backends, yes.

Comment: there is a problem with that approach. Serverside-rendered react component will not contain javascript, so the page will not have significant functions. 
   
I need to have reactjs components in the middle of serverside-rendered blade template.

Comment: so if you're doing client side rendering, why do you need the nodejs server?

Comment: good question)
So, all i need is to inject reactjs's main javascript file into the website and make it rendering in certain dom elements?
If so - this is too easy)

Comment: If you render it like that - how are you meant to pass props to the component from the php template?

Comment: There is another way. Generating all data-reactid attributes during PHP rendering. Or use v8 extension https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js